# Is this the right way to check if the mouseclick coordinates are within these ranges?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to check if the mouseclick is within a square of 400 by 400, is this the right way?

```
if turtle.xcor() >= -500 and turtle.xcor()<= -100:
    if turtle.ycor() >= -300 and turtle.ycor()<= 100:
        print('Goede zet')
else:
    print('Foutieve zet')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine but here you are calling `turtle.xcor()` and `turtle.ycor()` each twice. Alternatively, you can combine your conditions getting rid of `and` by just using the following syntax where you just put your variable within the range in which you want to check

```
if -500 <=turtle.xcor()<= -100:
    if -300<=turtle.ycor()<= 100:
        print('Goede zet')
else:
    print('Foutieve zet')
```

Since your second `if` is dependent on first `if`, another shorter version using a single `if` statement is

```
if (-500 <=turtle.xcor()<= -100) and (-300<=turtle.ycor()<= 100):
        print('Goede zet')
else:
    print('Foutieve zet')
```

Comment: Thanks, i will take the hints with me. I have used this now:

    if turtle.xcor() in range(-500,-100) and turtle.ycor() in range(-300,100):
        print('Goede zet')
    else:
        print('Foutieve zet')

And it worked also!

Comment: @R.R.: Yes there could be several answers.